# graphs and charts on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, charts

My client has requested data to be presented in a graphical format on the iPhone (a pie chart or something similar). I am wondering how others have handled this - A.) deliver the raw data to the phone and somehow build the chart on the phone, or B.) have the back-end services build the chart and deliver it (png format) to the phone?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graph generation on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794562/graph-generation-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to use the Google ChartAPI:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/pie_charts.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out Core Plot.

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/