# How to display graph in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I m new in iphone..I create Application in which I maintain data About Income ,Expenses, & total balance .I need to display that information in Graph..

Question:- How I display graph in my Iphone  application???like suppose If total balance is 1000 and income is 500 then In graph It displays overall graph contains total balacne means 100% and income will Be display as its 20%

---

Now I get the graph in my application BY using CorePlot But I provide static data ON Axis..I want to display Data from Database.. How can I do that??

Comment: Check this SO post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794562/graph-generation-on-iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), it's easy to use and there are samples for almost all the graphs...

Comment: I already know that but How i Start to learn that..  I m confused..can u guide me What I do First from that link??

Comment: Core plot is good for small datasets, but it's really slow. There's a performance comparison here which compares against iOS-Charts, Coreplot, and two commercial charts for larger datasets, or frequent update: https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-performance-comparison

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using core plot or an google api that needs an internet connection you can draw a graph yourself using quartz 2d. That's what I did for my app. CorePlot was kind of tricky to install and it seems complicated for small projects.

http://buildmobile.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d-part-3/

The advantage of drawing the graphs yourself is that you learn to use the standard drawing apis from Apple. Good luck

Comment: I just recently implemented my own graphing  library that I feel is pretty easy to use. Check it out. https://github.com/jsetting32/JSGraphKit

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use google chart api, I use this in all my apps.

see the tutorial here,

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/making_charts.html

you will directly get image as per your requirement just by making one HTTP Request.

Comment: Hadley:- I check it..But I have to Make graph..so can u suggest me for that I dnt need to use Chart Using Get & Post method..

Comment: ok Rami , which graph do you want to draw ? , simple line graph ? or any else ?

Comment: simple line graph...I m just create it first time so i want to clear concept about graph in  iphone

Comment: then you should go to http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html

Comment: Which framework and classes I Have to copy or add in my application to display the graph??

Comment: Why don't you try downloading core-plot, reading the documentation they provide, trying the examples and using search functions (google is your friend). You are going to have to do some of this....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw graphs in iPhone applications using Objective-C or Swift, you can use [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com), which supports over 20 popular chart types, including Column and Bar.

There are some really nice examples over at the scichart website for drawing chart types in Objective-C and Swift.

For instance:

- [iOS Column Chart Example](https://www.scichart.com/example/ios-column-chart-demo/)
- [iOS Stacked Column Chart Example](https://www.scichart.com/example/ios-chart-stacked-column-100-percent-chart-example/)
- [iOS Bar Chart Example](https://www.scichart.com/example/ios-chart-stacked-bars-chart-example/)

[Examples are also hosted on Github](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.iOS.Examples/) and there are also [tutorials](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/v2.x/webframe.html#Tutorial%2001%20-%20Linking%20SciChart%20Framework.html) to help you learn this powerful tool.

[image].

*As a disclosure, i am the tech lead on the scichart project*