# CorePlot: creating bands with mutable widths (changing based on data)

Tags: ios, graph, customization, core-plot, cptxygraph

I would like to create a **CorePlot** graph with dynamic bands (**changing as the time goes along**), a little bit like this ugly drawing here (forgive me for the quality):

[image]

Basically the band colouring should change based on some values/criteria. The yellow band can be **wider** or **thinner** and so can the white and green band. **In other words these bands need to have dynamic width**

This is the current way I set the y graph band colouring, however if I dynamically change it it does not work as it changes them all (I just want to change the band dynamically in a specific area of the graph and not all of it).

Any idea how I can achieve this?

This is the **code related to the band**:

```
CPTFill *whitebandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
CPTFill *greenbandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
CPTFill *redbandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75]];

 [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(500.0)] fill:whitebandFill]];
[y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(500.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(750.0)] fill:greenbandFill]];

 [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(750.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1024.0)] fill:redbandFill]];
```

This is my **complete** current source code:

```
self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
self.allData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Create a CPTGraph object and add to hostView
self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphHostView.bounds];
self.graphHostView.hostedGraph = self.graph;

CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
titleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
titleStyle.fontName = @"Futura";
titleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;

//////////
// Axes
// Label x axis with a fixed interval policy
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.separateLayers              = NO;
x.title                       = @"X Axis";
x.titleTextStyle              = titleStyle;
```

colorWithAlphaComponent:CPTFloat(0.1)], [[CPTColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:CPTFloat(0.1)]];
    x.delegate                    = self;

```
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.separateLayers        = YES;
y.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                        [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:0],
                        [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:300],
                        nil];

y.title                 = @"Y Axis";
y.titleTextStyle        = titleStyle;
```

colorWithAlphaComponent:CPTFloat(0.3)], [NSNull null]];
    y.delegate              = self;

```
CPTFill *whitebandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
CPTFill *greenbandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
CPTFill *redbandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75]];

 [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(500.0)] fill:whitebandFill]];
[y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(500.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(750.0)] fill:greenbandFill]];

 [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(750.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1024.0)] fill:redbandFill]];

self.graph.axisSet.axes = @[x, y];
```

Comment: @ErickSkroch would you be please able to have a look at this question?

Answer (score 1):

Limit bands always extend across the plot area in strait lines. You can draw more complex shapes by using additional plots. Set the `areaFill` to draw a fill between the plot line and the `areaBaseValue`.

Comment: Hello Eric, I have tried to modify the CandleStick example using your suggestion but I am unable to create more than 2 bands of colour. I need to be able to recreate the example in my question with 3 different colours. Any idea on how I can achieve this? A scattered plot has only two areaFill and two areaBase. What happens to those when we want to have two scattered plots? How can I make sure that they don't overlap? I need one plot to finish when the other one starts .. basically imagine the image above with 5 different colour bands.. how would you update the candlestick to support this

Comment: You can use more than one plot for the background. One for the yellow part and one for the green part. The plot area fill will show through between them. Right now, there's no easy way to fill between two plots (see [issue #99](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/99)). You could try to draw a closed shape with a third scatter plot if you need to fill that space. If you want to plots to draw next to each other, just give then the same data values along the common section.