# native iphone graphing library?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know of a native graphing library for the iPhone SDK? I have a free iPhone polling app called Show of Hands that currently uses calls to google charts via embedded safari pages, e.g. http://www.showofhands.mobi/Viewmore.aspx?qid=9245968c-d40d-478c-8781-804d086cd643 . Pros: free and easy and web-accessible. Cons: slower and less flexible within the app than native. So...I'm exploring options for handling the graphing and mapping functionality natively, without needing to roll my own.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

-tony

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Answer (score 1):

Thread on this here: [Is there a good charting library for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769749/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-iphone)

[CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot) seems to be the concensus so far, but still evolving.

This thread: [Any good library for generating graphs for the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879812/any-good-library-for-generating-graphs-for-the-iphone) also had a great point:

> In terms of embedding a JavaScript
>   charting library, you can always use a
>   WebKit view to host a web page
>   containing whatever JavaScript you
>   want. You will likely be [interested in
>   this sample code showing how to call
>   into JS from Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/CallJS/index.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/DTS10004241) and visa
>   versa.

You could try that with something like [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) or other js libraries.