# Creating Graphs on an iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, graphing

I was wondering if anyone knew of a simple way to implement graphing in an iPhone/iPad application.  I've spent quite a bit of time googling and can't seem to find *any* sort of a solution.  Maybe I'm just searching with the wrong terms since a lot of consumers are asking about "graphing" in terms of using their applications, not developing them, the search-space is rather polluted.

It seems like a lot of iPad/iPhone applications have embedded graphs... and I can't imagine that every developer has invented their own graphing engine from the ground up.  Or, maybe they have...  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is one popular option.

Comment: That looks awesome.  Will be marking as answer when the window expires.  :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have herd wonders about core plot but for myself i wrote a graph View Class which creates a standard graph.

Have a look

http://sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone/

hope it helps

Comment: hey. could you please provide the sample code for this thing. the sample code in the site where the link takes me is not working        Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience graphs are best done through UIWebView's and then written in HTML/JavaScript - there are many great html/javascript libraries for graphings.  Personally, I like

- http://www.highcharts.com

but these exist as well.

- http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts
- https://developers.google.com/chart/
- http://www.zingchart.com/#welcome