# Graph visualization libraries on iphone

Tags: iphone, graph

Are there are any libraries that are available for visualizing graphs for iphone sdk? Something like [this](http://prefuse.org/gallery/graphview/). There is no need for any animation. Simple laying out of graph is fine. Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Comment: Please look at the link I posted. I am interested in graph visualization. Not pie chart/bar graph etc.

Comment: Sorry about that, "graph visualization" can have different meanings depending on the context.  In this case, you mean display of a mathematical graph of connected items, rather than a graph of data points.

Comment: duplicate of [Looking for a graph layout framework for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692840/looking-for-a-graph-layout-framework-for-ios) which has a lot of useful answers based around talking Glen Low into releasing or licensing his port of GraphViz

Answer (score 2):

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is a plotting framework for Mac OS X and iPhone OS. It provides 2D visualization of data, and is tightly integrated with Apple technologies like Core Animation, Core Data, and Cocoa Bindings.

Comment: Does this do graph visualization? I checked out the link, it seems to be doing mostly line graphs/ bar graphs/pie charts. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Core Plot is the only one I know of that does graphs but this probably does not answer your question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple but very effective implementation for graphs. Check it out:

https://github.com/freshking/DynamicGraphView