# Looking for a graph layout framework for iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, graph, ios, graph-layout

For an iOS application I'm making I need to show groups of elements grouped together according to their type, and different groups of types separated from each other in a nicely done layout.

I thought of using an undirected graph, with the grouped nodes all pointing to each other in a sort of circular reference, and then each group as another "meta-graph" with their nodes point at each other in a circular reference as well, hoping that together with a good graph layout framework this could be displayed nicely.

Unfortunately, the only framework I keep hearing of is [graphviz](http://graphviz.org), but that doesn't seem to have an available port for iOS.

So my question is either:

1. Other ideas for how to implement what I need?
2. A good implementation of graph layout for the iOS?
3. An available port of graphviz for the iOS?

**Update**: Please note, I am **not** looking for graph *plotting* frameworks, which are the frameworks used to *draw* graphs and charts (such as pie charts etc). I am looking for a *layout* framework which determines the optimal location for arbitrary nodes in an abstract graph.

Comment: Do you want your application to dynamically generate these elements and display the graph to the user? Do the graphs need to be interactive?

Comment: @Michael No idea about the OP, but I have the same question and "yes, maybe not". :)

Comment: @Michael: yep, the application allows for element creation and element interaction. However, the interaction is in a different "phase" of the workflow so they can be non-interactive while their location is determined.

Comment: This question asked something similar a while ago, but we misinterpreted what he meant by graph visualization in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960308/graph-visualization-libraries-on-iphone

Comment: @Brad: I agree, you did misinterpret him. But how does this help me? I don't need Core Plot either :)

Comment: @Aviad Ben Dov - Normally, you'd close the newer question as a duplicate of the old one, but you've asked a better question here so I just wanted to link the two in case someone answered the old one.

Comment: @Brad: Ahh.. Okay! Understood! Hopefully someone will answer here... :-/

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824215/graph-plotting-framework-for-ios

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to a [post](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-devel/2008/000850.html) on the graphviz development mailing list, 
Glen Low of pixelglow has already managed to port graphviz and uses it in [Instaviz](http://instaviz.com/).

He also has some [hints](http://old.nabble.com/Re:-graphviz-on-iphone---p24112815.html) on the configure script.

Comment: I read about pixelglow. I tried contacting Glen Low, and if he'll open source the port I'll post it back here.

Comment: Okay, correcting my previous comment: I'll try the configure and the instructions there. If it works, great!

Comment: @spenthil: the instructions won't work. I couldn't figure it out though; after I try the build, it would shout "error: conditional "INSTALL_LTDL" was never defined". That is expected, as the instructions say not to install LTDL. Have any idea why this breaks the build?

Comment: Did you try adding `--disable-ltdl` to the configure?

Comment: BTW, I'm a he and not a she, says Glen. I have a suitable configure script embedded within an Xcode project that will build a libgraphviz.a, but currently it only works for Graphviz 2.24. Haven't updated it for the latest release yet.

Comment: *Extremely* sorry Glen - I have corrected it above.

Answer (score 3):

Below are some libraries which might help you:

1) http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

2) http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/

3) https://github.com/duivesteyn-net/deSimpleChart

4) http://www.rgraph.net/ (Will work on UIWebView only)

5) http://sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone/ (a blog where demo is given to create a graph)

Comment: Thanks for your help but these are graph plotting frameworks, and not graph layout frameworks. I'll add a note stating that this is NOT what I need specifically, since it seems a lot of people are confused about this.

Answer (score 1):

graphviz is C source and has been ported to OSX/Xcode already.  I would try to build a library in Xcode from source -- not a dylib (because that's not allowed on iOS devices), but a .a library.  I bet the code is pretty close to portable to iOS already if not fully so.

Comment: Thought of that and even tried playing with it for a bit. Things weren't as simple though, but perhaps I'm not proficient in how to do it: should sources be added before or after a call to ./configure for example?

Comment: In other words, how do you suggest approaching such a solution? :)

Comment: I'm not really sure.  The purpose of configure is to make you a makefile.  Here's what I would do (1) figure out how to call configure in a way that targets iPhone target, starting with simulator (2) Call make to get a .a (3) use the .a in my project.

Comment: That's where I am extremely lacking knowledge: make and configure. I've been trying to play with configure for a few days now with no major success. I don't even know how to make gcc to compile for the armv7 architecture (even though Xcode seems to support it!). It's all quite fascinatingly new, and I have little time to study it properly.. Help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about using Google Chart in a webview:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: I'm looking for an more-or-less abstract layout engine, not a powerpoint-like chart engine. Thanks anyway! :)