# Anyone know iOS library or sample for drawing diagrams like mind maps/ visio/ gra

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, ios4, core-graphics

Anyone know iOS library or sample for drawing diagrams like mind maps/ visio/ graphing sw.
Doesnt have to be full library or full example.
Can be UIKit or OpenGLES

I want to have a app that is like a tree structure with root topic the sub topic etc.
Clicking on root will open subfolders and so on and they get laid out so they dont over lap.

Im on Safari so if you know a book with an example I should be able to find that too.

cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a graph layout framework for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692840/looking-for-a-graph-layout-framework-for-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Graphviz port, [Instaviz](http://instaviz.com/). If the layout quality matches what you need, contact Glen, the author, and see if you can license the layout and rendering portions.

Answer (score 1):

Quartz 2D should work quite well for you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you want to go OpenGLES then the best tutorials are here:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html