# How to display Graphs on iphone

Tags: iphone, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can any one suggest good tutorial to display Graphs on iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Comment: Sorry, now that I look at it you want object graphs, not plotting.  In that case, this question asks the same thing: [Looking for a graph layout framework for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692840/looking-for-a-graph-layout-framework-for-ios)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [TapkuLibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary), specifically `TKGraphController`.

Answer (score -1):

Nice library: Core-Plot: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/
or: http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/