# How can I draw bar chart and pie chart iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display bar chart and pie chart in my iPhone application please give me suggestions for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot) is a plotting framework for Mac OS X and iOS. It provides 2D visualization of data, and is tightly integrated with Apple technologies like Core Animation, Core Data, and Cocoa Bindings.

Answer (score 5):

Try [iOS Plot](https://github.com/honcheng/iOSPlot) and [iPhone Charting](http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/).

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is also a good option.

Below are some libraries which could also help you:

- [Graph View](http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/)
- [deSimpleChart](http://github.com/duivesteyn-enterprises/deSimpleChart)
- [rgraph](http://www.rgraph.net/) (Will work on UIWebView only)
- [Graph classes for iPhone](http://sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone/) (a blog where demo is given to create a graph)
- [Looking for a graph layout framework for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692840/looking-for-a-graph-layout-framework-for-ios)

Finally, there's some nice discussion about [charting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/julijanpiechart.aspx) here.

Answer (score 0):

I used this lib on GitHub -> https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts. This lib is absolutely perfect and free. Also same lib is available in android and native. You can also find a lot of types of chart in this lib.