# Are there any libraries or APIs for creating charts on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Are there any libraries or APIs for creating different types of charts on the iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).