# Can i make Charts in Iphone . Using any Framework

Tags: iphone, charts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Suggest Framework for making chart in Iphone application..

Comment: https://github.com/ameizi/awesome-ios-chart

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 0):

yes, check the following framework [Core-Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion - if you wants a easy way then try [google charts api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)